# php update m3u8 file before curl file

Tags: php, curl, m3u8

I have m3u8 file like that

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:561
#EXTINF:10.799611,
_c10_262_c10_148_c10_561.ts
#EXTINF:9.599644,
_c10_262_c10_148_c10_562.ts
#EXTINF:9.599667,
_c10_262_c10_148_c10_563.ts
#EXTINF:10.799611,
_c10_262_c10_148_c10_564.ts
#EXTINF:9.599667,
_c10_262_c10_148_c10_565.ts
#EXTINF:9.599644,
_c10_262_c10_148_c10_566.ts
```

I want to read it to redirect client to it

My code is

```
$dir = "/var/www/media/";
$playfile = 'curl --silent "file://'.$dir.'file.m3u8" 2>/dev/null';
header('Content-Type: video/mp2t');
mysql_close($sqlconnection);
@system($playfile, $output);
exit();
```

When I connect to link I redirect to file correct but when redirect to file that m3u8 included it give error

I need to regenerate file before redirect client

i use curl to excute it with client username to know if he is online or no... i need to hide my m3u8 file from web root and save it in local path

Comment: "i use curl to excute it with client username" - there is no username mentioned in your example code, and I can't imagine how using curl to access a local file would ever be different from using normal file access functions.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using curl, and via a shell to boot? A simple `ceho file_get_contents()` should be more than sufficient in this case.

Also, if you need to regenerate the file on each load (which is another "why?"), then you should already have the entire contents of the file in a variable. Just `print` said variable to the client, instead of doing the whole roundtrip via the filesystem and shell commands.

For a dynamically generated file, it would look something like this:

```
$m3u = generate_playlist ($mediaFolder);
header ('Content-Type: video/mp2t');
echo $m3u;
die();
```

For a static file:

```
header ('Content-Type: video/mp2t');
echo file_get_contents ($file);
die();
```

Note that the call to `die()` is not necessary if this is the last line the code (branch). PHP will naturally `die` on the last line of code anyway.

PS: A good tip for future posts. Whenever you're asking for help on how to do something, please provide the reasoning for why you want to do it. Most of the time there's a better method, but we can only provide it if we know what you want to do, and why you want to do it. ;)

Comment: thank you, i use curl to excute it with client username to know if he is online or no... i need to hide my m3u8 file from web root and save it in local path

Comment: Not sure why you'd need to use cURL to determine whether a user is online or not, that should already be handled by your PHP script's login routines. Both of my examples will allow you to place the m3u8 file outside of the web root, in fact in my first example there is no actual file saved anywhere.
You're welcome, and I hope you find my answers useful.